# How to read another audio stream when performing transform on one audio stream?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have two `MediaStreamAudioTrack`s (Processor), each of whom produces `AudioData` through a `ReadableStream<AudioData>`.

I'd like to read another track when transforming one of these tracks, whose signature is like:

```
class {
  refReader: ReadableStreamDefaultReader<AudioData>
    = refTrackProcessor.readable.getReader();

  async transform(
    data: AudioData,
    controller: TransformStreamDefaultController<AudioData>
  ) {
    const { value: refData } = await this.refReader.read()
  }
}
```

This transform function gets called for around 100 times a second (per 10 ms).
But `await reader.read()` costs a lot of milliseconds of 8ms+ or so, which causes `controller.enqueue(processedData)` enqueued data to be late and audio sounds very ka-le.

Is there a best practice to read another audio stream in munging one audio stream?

p.s. the case like AEC